# In Elevator Phone Connectivity Reuirements ASME 2019 is WIFI bridging Acceptable?

Tags: wifi, regulations

What is acceptable connectivity for an Elevator Phone system. As analog systems are going by the way side, Cellular is one option, however is it acceptable to use point to point WIFI bridging to accomplish this task and where in the code regulations is the information regarding this ?

Comment: Ooooh, I wouldn't like to be stuck in a lift relying on a bunch of WiFi routers, switches and VoIP telephony. If any one of them fails or loses power then you're stuck. You can't beat a wired connection.

Comment: @Transistor wired connections are going bye bye.. no more plain ole telephone.

Comment: I'll settle for a big bell and strobe light then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard seems to specify 2-way communications, with requirements for testing, alternate power, etc., but does not specify how that should work.

There are a lot of requirements there, but they seem to leave to you how to make it work.  The applicable section is 2.27.1 Car Signaling Devices.